# Does a weekday preceded with a plural definite article express regular events?

Tags: meaning, articles

I know that "il martedì" in "il martedì mangio formaggio" means "on Tuesdays" (a regular event). Could I say "i martedì mangio formaggio" instead ? I have read it for the first time today and I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: I think the answer in your previous question would apply here too.

Comment: ***Il martedì*** o ***tutti i martedì*** io mangio formaggio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As correctly stated in a comment to your question you have 2 options:

1. "Il martedì mangio formaggio."
2. "Tutti i martedì mangio formaggio", but also "ogni martedì mangio formaggio".

So, to reply to your question, you cannot say "i martedì mangio formaggio", but "tutti i martedì mangio formaggio" or it will sound incomplete.

"On tuesdays" = "il martedì" = "tutti i martedì".

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So I have 3 options, not 2.